# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (object file does not exist)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, linker, qt-creator

I am trying to build someone else's QT project that they built and created on Linux, I am trying to build it on a Mac.

However, I am getting the error message "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64".

[image: image of error and .cpp file]

error message:

```
vieworder.cpp.o:-1: error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "pqxx::row::row(pqxx::result const&, int)", referenced from:
      pqxx::const_result_iterator::const_result_iterator(pqxx::result const*, int) in vieworder.cpp.o
  "pqxx::internal::check_pqxx_version_7_6()", referenced from:
      pqxx::check_version() in main.cpp.o
  "pqxx::field::name() const", referenced from:
      ViewOrder::on_statusBtn_clicked() in vieworder.cpp.o
  "pqxx::field::c_str() const", referenced from:
      pqxx::field::view() const in homewindow.cpp.o
      ViewOrder::on_historyBtn_clicked() in vieworder.cpp.o
      ViewOrder::on_statusBtn_clicked() in vieworder.cpp.o
```

Thanks!

Comment: we'd need a [mre] but presumably you need to link to libpqxx

Comment: do you know how to do that with CMake/qt

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html